# Store data from a txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
ID Number Hour Name Mood Seconds Hour2
1 29.1 11:32:37 Tim Good 0954 11:32:34 PM
2 31.9 11:33:19 Tim Fine 1251 11:33:15 PM
3 32.0 11:54:16 Tim Excellent 1897 11:54:12 PM
4 36.6 12:00:43 Time Good 0997 12:00:37 PM
```

As we can see, it is not a CSV value, as it is space separated instead. How can I store this data in variables (one for each column)? Once I get this data stored in variables using html code or javascript or jQuery, I would like to plot them using [Flot Charts](http://www.flotcharts.org/), but this will come later.

Comment: Look for whitespace and line breaks, that's the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that should work. You might have to tweak it a bit, but this should help you.

So first we need to load the file and assign the value to a variable.

```
var fileContent;
$.ajax({
    url : "text.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        fileContent = data;
    }
});
```

You then, as I said have to look for spaces and line breaks. You know that when a line break occurs, it all "starts over" so to speak.

So let's use jQuery's `.split()` function, something like this:

```
var rows = fileContent.split("\n");
```

Now you should have an array with a length of 5, one per row. Loop through these and split these by `" "`. We skip the first row (index 0) since those aren't data. Also as commented, the last space has to be skipped, since that's a part of the data.

```
var id = "";
var number = "";
var hour = "";
var name = "";
var mood = "";
var seconds = "";
var hour2 = "";

var array = [id,number,hour,name,mood,seconds,hour2];
for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++){
    var columns = rows[j].split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if(i == 5){
            $array[i].= columns[i]+" "+columns[i+1];
            break;
        }

        array[i].= columns[i];
    }
}
console.log(array);
```

This should help you a lot. Might not be perfect, but you get the idea.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I'm not sure if I know how to load it. What I would do is: 

var data= new XMLHttpRequest();
data.open('GET', '/data.txt');
data.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(data.responseText);
}
data.send();

But I do not know how the data will be structured. I code a lot in MATLAB and it is easy to observe how the data is stored in variables, but here as it is impossible to see it, it drives me crazy.

I would like to just read the data, store it in something similar as vectors (for example: vector1(0)=29.1 , vector1(1)=31.9 and so on). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks very much again! Now I think I get it at least. When I load the html file into Firefox I get a blank page... I tried the Firefox console and I get the following JS error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Do you know where this error could be? Furthermore,does the console.log statement display the result? (As it would be useful to see the results before plotting them in Flot Charts). Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it. In the next comment I will post the html code I'm using just in case you need it :).

Comment: @jquery_stack I edited the code in my post, found two misses. And the console.log outputs the variable in the browsers console. So if you inspect in the web browser you should see it there.

Comment: The full code is in this image: http://imgur.com/8T0S42t. I tried to add the <?php ?php> statement just in case but I am getting another error. If I write without the <php statement I get SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (located in the foreach statement line). If I type the <php statement, I get SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' (located right at the <?php statement. Do you have any idea of what happens? HUGE THANKS!

Comment: @jquery_stack Remove the <?php ... ?> surrounding the foreach. That's javascript

Comment: Apparently I got the error solved but in the Firefox console no text is displayed :(

Comment: Is the var "fileContent" set? Run console.log on it @jquery_stack

Comment: Apparently it does not like the foreach(rows as row) statement. It is saying that there is a SyntaxError before "as". This is the full code I'm using, syntaxerror at line 27 (don't know why foreach isn't highlighted with a different colour) and nothing printed in screen: http://imgur.com/9KJijaL

Comment: @jquery_stack Changed it into a for-loop. Updated my answer. Check it out

Comment: Getting closer! I did run console.log(fileContent) and it was displayed. However, I get an error on the code saying  that in  var rows = fileContent.split("\n"); filecontent is UNDEFINED. How strange... I'm able to perform a console.log on it but perhaps is out of an important statement or I don't know... I've checked the code that I attached in the image and seems fine :S

Comment: Maybe I'm placing var rows in the wrong place, otherwise I'm clueless how this can be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Split data into rows. Then split the first row and take the result as the keys for the other data/rows. After that, try to prevent undefined columns ('PM') and add the result to the previous column.

```js
var data = 'ID Number Hour Name Mood Seconds Hour2\n1 29.1 11:32:37 Tim Good 0954 11:32:34 PM\n1 31.9 11:33:19 Tim Fine 1251 11:33:15 PM\n3 32.0 11:54:16 Tim Excellent 1897 11:54:12 PM\n4 36.6 12:00:43 Time Good 0997 12:00:37 PM';
var newData = [], keys;
data.split('\n').forEach(function (row, i) {
    var res;
    if (!i) {
        keys = row.split(' ');
    } else {
        res = {};
        row.split(' ').forEach(function (el, j) {
            if (keys[j]) {
                res[keys[j]] = el;
            } else {
                res[keys[j - 1]] += ' ' + el; // time correction
            }
        });
        newData.push(res);
    }
});
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newData, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```